# Rails form processing as HTML instead of JS

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms

In my Rails app, I have a form that should be submitted through ajax (remote is set to true).  The form lets users either add an embedded video or upload a video file to the app.  I created the form by using bootstrap tabs in a modal.

[image]

When I submit an embedded video using the first tab in the form, the form is successfully processed as JS.  However, when I attempt to upload a video using the second tab in the form, the form is incorrectly processed as HTML.

How can I ensure that the form is always processed as JS?

**view:**

```
<%= semantic_form_for Video.new,
    :html => {:id => "videoEmbedModal", :class => "modal hide fade embedModal"}, 
    :remote => true do |video_form| %>

    <%= video_form.input :project_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => @project.id} %>
       <% if @step.new_record? %>
           <%= video_form.input :step_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => -1} %>
           <%= video_form.input :saved, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => false} %>
       <% else %>
           <%= video_form.input :step_id, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => @step.id} %>
           <%= video_form.input :saved, :as => :hidden, :label => false, :input_html => {:value => true} %>
       <% end %>

  <div class="modal-header">
    <h3>Add a Video</h3>
  </div>

<div class="modal-body">

  <div class="tabbable">
    <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="add_video_tabs">
      <li class="active">
        <a href="#embed_video">Embed Video</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#upload_video">Upload Video</a>
      </li>

    </ul>

    <div class="tab-content" style="margin-top: 10px;">
      <% # add embedded video tab %>
      <div class="tab-pane active" id="embed_video">
        <%= video_form.label "Video URL", :class=> "label" %><span style="font-size:smaller; color: #7E7E7E; margin-left:10px">We currently support Youtube and Vimeo</span>
        <%= video_form.text_area :embed_url, 
            :placeholder => "Example: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bVj85o5hA_Q", :rows=>"2", :cols=>"50" %>

      <div class="supportedVideo">
        <i class="icon-youtube" style="font-size: 25px"></i> <%= image_tag "icons/Vimeo.png", :class=>"vimeo_icon" %><br>
      </div>

      <div class="embedPreview">
        <h3>Video Preview</h3>
      </div>
    </div>


    <% # upload video tab %>
    <div class="tab-pane" id="upload_video">
      <div class="supported-video-files">
        We support .mp4, .mov, and .avi video files.
      </div>
      <div id="uploadVideoField">
        <%= video_form.file_field :video_path, :class=>"video_file_upload_field", :onchange=> "return validateFileExtension(this)" %>
      </div>
      <div class="btn btn-warning btn-small" style="margin-top:10px; display:none;">Remove</div>
      <br>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="modal-footer">
  <%= video_form.actions do %>
  <%= video_form.action :cancel, :label => "Close", :as => :link,
  :button_html => {:class => "btn modal_close_btn", :href => "#", 
  :data => {:target => "#videoEmbedModal", :toggle => "modal"}} %>

  <%= video_form.action :submit, :label => "Save", :as => :button,
  :button_html => {:class => "btn btn-primary", :id => "video_submit", :disable_with => "Saving..."}, :disable_with => "Saving..." %>
  <% end %>
  <div class="loadingIcon"></div>
</div>

<% end %>
```

**Log messages for adding embedded video:**

```
Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-16 13:52:51 -0400
Processing by VideosController#create as JS
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YuHlkYWPJK7oAkKXoLAebUQLGWuTrX/RMabOzLfITkM=", "video"=>{"project_id"=>"13", "step_id"=>"-1", "saved"=>"false", "embed_url"=>"http://vimeo.com/73388765"}, "button"=>""}
![][2]
```

**Log messages for adding uploaded video:**

```
Running transcoding...
ffmpeg -y -i /public/uploads/tmp/1381945989-16853-6328/Untitled.mov -vcodec libx264 -acodec libfaac -s 640x360  -qscale 0 -preset slow -g 30 -aspect 1.7777777777777777 /public/uploads/tmp/1381945989-16853-6328/tmpfile.mp4

Transcoding of /public/uploads/tmp/1381945989-16853-6328/Untitled.mov to /public/uploads/tmp/1381945989-16853-6328/tmpfile.mp4 succeeded



Started POST "/videos" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-10-16 13:53:09 -0400
**Processing by VideosController#create as HTML**
  Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"YuHlkYWPJK7oAkKXoLAebUQLGWuTrX/RMabOzLfITkM=", "video"=>{"project_id"=>"13", "step_id"=>"-1", "saved"=>"false", "embed_url"=>"", "video_path"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007f8a11393cd8 @original_filename="Untitled.mov", @content_type="video/quicktime", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"video[video_path]\"; filename=\"Untitled.mov\"\r\nContent-Type: video/quicktime\r\n", @tempfile=#<File:/var/folders/dc/c0nfvwy96lq7p4ll94mklnmr0000gp/T/RackMultipart20131016-16853-qmwjfn>>}, "button"=>""}
```

**EDIT**
I completely removed the embedded video tab and just tried submitting the video using the filefield, and it's still being processed as HTML.  So I've isolated that the problem doesn't have to do with the way the form is set up in tabs.  I think it might have to do with the Gem I'm using to upload video files (carrierwave-video), but I'm still not sure, so if anyone is able to shed any light, it would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Have you tried ":multipart => :true" for your form?

Comment: I had forgotten to add multipart: true to my form and just did, but it's still being processed as HTML instead of JS.

Comment: What about :remote => :true ?

Comment: remote is true is already set

Answer (score 0):

When you click on the upload video does it cause a javascript error which 'kills' the javascript processing and causes the form to be submitted as HTML instead of JS?

Comment: Do you have a suggestion for how to check for this?  I checked the browser javascript console and didn't see any errors when I tried submitting the form.

Comment: I was hoping the error console would show you something. One option would be to add some on submit javascript which would show an alert .. If javascript is not working anymore at that point it would likely not trigger the alert.
I also notice that in the submit button you have twice :disable_with

Comment: thanks for your help.  I removed the double disable_with.  I also added an alert when the submit button is clicked, which works.  I'm not sure if it's an issue with javascript being disabled.  Is there a way to force the form to be processed as JS in the controller?

Comment: I noticed your edit .. Perhaps this link gives some insight in how to solve things with carrierwave:
http://quickleft.com/blog/how-to-upload-to-carrierwave-with-javascript

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to get the form to process as JS when using the submit button, but I ended up using jquery file upload to automatically process the form as JS once the user selects a file.   I did this with

```
$('#videoEmbedModal').fileupload();
```

Which then processes the form as JS.